# IMemoryCache and metrics on items count

Tags: c#, .net, caching

I have a service that is supposed to cache some API responses.
The docs of `IMemoryCache` suggest that I should use `AddMemoryCache` and inject `IMemoryCache` into my caching service. As part of my caching service, I'd like to record metrics regarding items stored in the cache.

Since `AddMemoryCache` registers `MemoryCache` as a singleton, it's not going to work for me. I could have a few services, each one caching some totally separate data. I want my metrics to show cached items in only one of my services.
Then, should I create `MemoryCache` separately for each class that needs it? Documentation in that area doesn't seem to exist.

Note that I'm using https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/, not the older System.Runtime.Caching mechanism.